# How to loop pyspark dataframe column value for conditional calculations

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I Have a pyspark dataframe, i want to pick specific column data and want to use it pick values based on condition.

Sample dataframe:

```
-----+-----+-----+-----+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID    |data                                                                                                                          |
+------+-----+-----+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1    |{"elements": [{{"sev": {"imp":"M","TIME":"20","min_lim":"10"}},{"sev": {"imp":"H","TIME":"10","min_lim":"5","max_lim:"10"}},{"sev": {"imp":"C","TIME":"5","min_lim":"1","max_lim:"4"}}}]}                                                                                    |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

schema:
df.printSchema
// root
//  |-- ID: string (nullable = false)
//  |-- data: string (nullable = true)
```

I want to fetch data value which is string type and i have variable like limit = 3, so i need to check max_limit and min_limit with limit variable value, based on match want to pick imp and TIME values

ex: if limit =7 , then imp=H and Time=10

```
Approach tried:

got data column into a variable

data_var = df.select('data').collect[0][0]

variable = ast(data_var)
```

converted into tuple and tried to add into list and loop them But i don;t feel it is efficient way to as i hard coded few things and input format can change in future.So can any one suggested better approach or solution for this

Comment: could u do df.printSchema() and provide required output too. it would help others answer your question.

Comment: Added schema result, both columns are string type